# Swift: How to handle wait time for parse queries

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, closures

I am making a Tinder like application where I query an array with parse and display the data in a deck of cards. I have a method where I query an array, and in the same method I use the returned list. However I get an error because the back card is called before the data is finished downloading. "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

How can I handle this so that the code waits for the query to be retrieved?

Thanks

```
import UIKit
import MDCSwipeToChoose

class ChoosePersonViewController: UIViewController, MDCSwipeToChooseDelegate {

var people:[Person] = []
let ChoosePersonButtonHorizontalPadding:CGFloat = 80.0
let ChoosePersonButtonVerticalPadding:CGFloat = 20.0
var currentPerson:Person!
var frontCardView:ChoosePersonView!
var backCardView:ChoosePersonView!
let nameData = ""

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    let userObjectID = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!
    let query = PFQuery(className:"Restaurants")
    query.whereKey("Pointer", equalTo: userObjectID)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    var nameData = object.objectForKey("Name") as? String
                    var imageData = object.objectForKey("Image") as? PFFile
                    imageData!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            if let imageData = imageData
                            {
                                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                                self.people.append(Person(name: nameData, image: image, age: 21, sharedFriends: 3, sharedInterest: 4, photos: 5))
                                print(self.people)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    // Here you can init your properties
    let imageData: PFFile

}

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
   // Display the first ChoosePersonView in front. Users can swipe to indicate
    // whether they like or dislike the person displayed.
    self.setMyFrontCardView(self.popPersonViewWithFrame(frontCardViewFrame())!)
    self.view.addSubview(self.frontCardView)

    // Display the second ChoosePersonView in back. This view controller uses
    // the MDCSwipeToChooseDelegate protocol methods to update the front and
    // back views after each user swipe.
    self.backCardView = self.popPersonViewWithFrame(backCardViewFrame())!
    self.view.insertSubview(self.backCardView, belowSubview: self.frontCardView)

    // Add buttons to programmatically swipe the view left or right.
    // See the `nopeFrontCardView` and `likeFrontCardView` methods.
    constructNopeButton()
    constructLikedButton()
}

func suportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}

// This is called when a user didn't fully swipe left or right.
func viewDidCancelSwipe(view: UIView) -> Void{

    print("You couldn't decide on \(self.currentPerson.Name)");
}

// This is called then a user swipes the view fully left or right.
func view(view: UIView, wasChosenWithDirection: MDCSwipeDirection) -> Void{

    // MDCSwipeToChooseView shows "NOPE" on swipes to the left,
    // and "LIKED" on swipes to the right.
    if(wasChosenWithDirection == MDCSwipeDirection.Left){
        print("You noped: \(self.currentPerson.Name)")
    }
    else{

        print("You liked: \(self.currentPerson.Name)")
    }

    // MDCSwipeToChooseView removes the view from the view hierarchy
    // after it is swiped (this behavior can be customized via the
    // MDCSwipeOptions class). Since the front card view is gone, we
    // move the back card to the front, and create a new back card.
    if(self.backCardView != nil){
        self.setMyFrontCardView(self.backCardView)
    }

    backCardView = self.popPersonViewWithFrame(self.backCardViewFrame())
    //if(true){
    // Fade the back card into view.
    if(backCardView != nil){
        self.backCardView.alpha = 0.0
        self.view.insertSubview(self.backCardView, belowSubview: self.frontCardView)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.backCardView.alpha = 1.0
            },completion:nil)
    }
}
func setMyFrontCardView(frontCardView:ChoosePersonView) -> Void{

    // Keep track of the person currently being chosen.
    // Quick and dirty, just for the purposes of this sample app.
    self.frontCardView = frontCardView
    self.currentPerson = frontCardView.person
}

func popPersonViewWithFrame(frame:CGRect) -> ChoosePersonView?{
    if(self.people.count == 0){
        return nil;
    }

    // UIView+MDCSwipeToChoose and MDCSwipeToChooseView are heavily customizable.
    // Each take an "options" argument. Here, we specify the view controller as
    // a delegate, and provide a custom callback that moves the back card view
    // based on how far the user has panned the front card view.
    let options:MDCSwipeToChooseViewOptions = MDCSwipeToChooseViewOptions()
    options.delegate = self
    //options.threshold = 160.0
    options.onPan = { state -> Void in
        if(self.backCardView != nil){
            let frame:CGRect = self.frontCardViewFrame()
            self.backCardView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y-(state.thresholdRatio * 10.0), CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetHeight(frame))
        }
    }

    // Create a personView with the top person in the people array, then pop
    // that person off the stack.

    let personView:ChoosePersonView = ChoosePersonView(frame: frame, person: self.people[0], options: options)
    self.people.removeAtIndex(0)
    return personView

}
```

Comment: Which line fails exactly? Why are you adding views like that as images load? You can't guarantee the order of the image loads...

Comment: The line that fails is "self.backCardView = self.popPersonViewWithFrame(self.backCardViewFrame())!" and how should I add the views?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that starting all the image downloads in a hard loop is ineffective and likely to lead to network flooding and multiple request timeouts.

Consider just storing all of the returned objects and requesting only the first (and perhaps second) images.

Add the views immediately after saving the returned items and deal with adding the image to the view when it becomes available.

It seems that your issue might actually be related to trying to remove a view which doesn't exist yet, though it isn't clear what that function does and it might be something more like it wants to access an object which hasn't been added to the array yet because the next image hasn't downloaded so it can't find / create a suitable item to return... Changing the way you use images and views will resolve either of these causes.

Comment: I am having a hard time conceptualizing how to code that. Can you push me in the right direction? Since the objects are asynchronous, I don't know where else to load the views besides within the block itself otherwise I get an error at "                                self.setMyFrontCardView(self.popPersonViewWithFrame(self.frontCardViewFrame())!)"

Comment: You need at most 2 views and 2 images at any one time, the current one and the next one. Technically the views can exist even if the images aren't ready yet. So, create the first 2 views immediately. Other views should be created when your transition animation ends (destroy the first view as its no longer required and create the second view off screen ready to animate in).

Comment: I've updated the code. I am trying to create the card views before the images load as you've suggested but it seems it is reliant on the people array to exist. I get an error at " self.setMyFrontCardView(self.popPersonViewWithFrame(self.frontCardViewFrame())!)‌​"

Comment: Because you access the person when doing it